# Parse JSON Data to SQL Table

Tags: arrays, sql-server, json

I have trawled the internet for the past two days without success so reluctantly here is my first question to the good people of Stack Overflow.

I am trying to transform JSON data to a SQL Server (2016) table but the data contains an array with no key. The JSON looks like so:

```
[
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 1,
    "day": 1,
    "breakdownTotal": [
      "283082",
      "601184",
      "140120"
    ]
  },
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 1,
    "day": 2,
    "breakdownTotal": [
      "354725",
      "760532",
      "177279"
    ]
  }
]
```

I can get the following table:

```
year    month   day
2016    1   1
2016    1   2
```

But ideally I would like to have:

```
year    month   day breakdown1  breakdown2  breakdown3
2016    1   1   283082  601184  140120
2016    1   2   354725  760532  177279
```

Though would be able to do something with:

```
year    month   day breakdown
2016    1   1   283082
2016    1   1   601184
2016    1   1   140120
2016    1   2   354725
2016    1   2   760532
2016    1   2   177279
```

This is similar to the example data at the top of this link:
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn921897.aspx][1] 
  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn921897.aspx though unhelpfully, these is no mention of how to extract the info.

Does anybody have any tips on how I could achieve the desired result? Any help would be much appreciated.

Rob

Comment: Maybe this could help you? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921879.aspx

Comment: your "ideally I would like to have" is not a normalised database. Not a good structure. Your "would be able to do something with" example is much better. If you want later to _output_ it like the first example, then you can do that separately using queries etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (thanks to @Danieboy for [the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921879.aspx) in the comments):

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @json='-paste your json here-';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (   
    [year]   int '$.year'   
    ,[month] int '$.month'  
    ,[day] int '$.day'  
    ,[breakdown1] bigint '$.breakdownTotal[0]'  
    ,[breakdown2] bigint '$.breakdownTotal[1]'  
    ,[breakdown3] bigint '$.breakdownTotal[2]'  
 ) 
;
```

Sadly I don't have SQL 2016 so haven't been able to test.

Comment: that works absolutely perfectly! Thanks for the speedy response, I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: No worries.  ps. Per @ADyson's comments on your question, please note that the above code assumes there will always be 3 values in the `breakdownTotal` array; any less and you'll get nulls for the superfluous columns, any more and they won't be included.